# Function cannot be used in the PIVOT operator because it is not invariant to NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL issue in which while I call I function from a pivot table I get this error:

> cannot be used in the PIVOT operator because it is not invariant to NULLs

I found the below link, but my issue is different because I use only the sql server
[Cannot be used in the PIVOT operator because it is not invariant to NULLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117714/cannot-be-used-in-the-pivot-operator-because-it-is-not-invariant-to-nulls)

I have a SP that gives the total working hour per day, the columns returned are the dates records in the table, the SP is working properly when I put under the dates the count of some data like this:

```
EMPId       01/08/2015  02/08/2015  03/08/2015  04/08/2015  05/08/2015  06/08/2015  07/08/2015  08/08/2015
000781      4           3           3           2           2           2           2           2
```

But when I want to change it to call the function that calculate the total working hour, I get the error.

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2015-08-01';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2015-08-08';
DECLARE @EmpID nvarchar(6) = '000781';

DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX)

select  @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME( cast(CONVERT( VARCHAR(20), date,103 ) as varchar(10)))   
                from   
                (  
                 select a1.date from (
                    SELECT DISTINCT date 
                    from PERS_Attendance
                    where Date between @StartDate AND @EndDate
                  )a1
                ) t

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')   
    ,1,1,'')  

EXEC(' SELECT EMPId,' + @cols + '
        from   
        (  
          select EMPId,
             date ,  
            funckey
          from  
          (  
            select convert(varchar(20), date,103)date, EMPId,funckey
            from PERS_Attendance
          ) src  
        ) x  
        pivot   
        (  
        dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(date,EMPId)
            for date in (' + @cols + ')  
        ) p where 1=1 ')
```

I get the error on this line:

```
dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(date,EMPId)
```

If I put the dynamic query in a variable then select it, I will get the below result:

```
SELECT EMPId,[01/08/2015],[02/08/2015],[03/08/2015],[04/08/2015],[05/08/2015],[06/08/2015],[07/08/2015],[08/08/2015]
from ( select EMPId, date , funckey from 
( select convert(varchar(20), date,103)date, EMPId,funckey from PERS_Attendance ) src ) x 
pivot ( dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(date,EMPId) for date in 
([01/08/2015],[02/08/2015],[03/08/2015],[04/08/2015],[05/08/2015],[06/08/2015],[07/08/2015],[08/08/2015]) )
p where 1=1
```

The errors returned was:

> Msg 406, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay cannot be used in the PIVOT operator because it is not invariant to NULLs.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'EMPId'.

I have already selected the empID, so why do I get an error on the empID?
How can I get the result of this function under the dates columns

Comment: You execute dynamic-sql so `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ... + ; SELECT @sql` Show actual code that will execute in EXEC.

Comment: i doesn't understand what do you mean?

Comment: Share `' SELECT EMPId,' + @cols + '
        from   
        (  
          select EMPId,
             date ,  
            funckey
          from  
          (  
            select convert(varchar(20), date,103)date, EMPId,funckey
            from PERS_Attendance
          ) src  
        ) x  
        pivot   
        (  
        dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(date,EMPId)
            for date in (' + @cols + ')  
        ) p where 1=1 '` after @cols is replaced by actual values

Comment: i have tried it before, but i got the some error

Comment: I don't want you execute it, I want that you paste it to question like `DECLARE @var INT = 1; EXEC('SELECT' + @var)` I want to see `SELECT 1`. Forget about EXEC

Comment: Just paste `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT EMPId,' + @cols + '
        from   
        (  
          select EMPId,
             date ,  
            funckey
          from  
          (  
            select convert(varchar(20), date,103)date, EMPId,funckey
            from PERS_Attendance
          ) src  
        ) x  
        pivot   
        (  
        dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(date,EMPId)
            for date in (' + @cols + ')  
        ) p where 1=1 '; SELECT @sql`, Paste result

Comment: Great add this to question. Your previous code generate code above. And it is executed.

Comment: Try to change `dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(date,EMPId)` to `SUM(dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(date,EMPId))`

Comment: i tried all the built-in function like (avg,sum,min,max...) but i got this non-logic small error :                       **Incorrect syntax near '('.**

Comment: @ziadmansour You can't use `dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(date,EMPId)` inside the `PIVOT` that way. The pivot function requires an aggregate function, you cannot call a stored procedure, another function, etc inside of PIVOT.  When you execute a sql string via `exec` the engine it processing the actual values, you're trying to calculate them on the fly via `GetWorkingHourPerDay` and that won't work...period.

Comment: thank you bluefeet for your info..and thank you for your vote down..i didn't found any information for unused function inside the pivot table..for that i asked my question

Comment: @ziadmansour The vote was not mine, I just commented on your question. Voting is anonymous, you can't know who voted for you.  It would be helpful if you included some sample data and the final desired result in your question to help you with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT EMPId,[01/08/2015],[02/08/2015],[03/08/2015],[04/08/2015],[05/08/2015],[06/08/2015],[07/08/2015],[08/08/2015]
from ( select EMPId, date , funckey, dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(date,EMPId) AS WorkingHours from 
( select convert(varchar(20), date,103)date, EMPId,funckey from PERS_Attendance ) src ) x 
pivot (MAX(WorkingHours) for date in 
([01/08/2015],[02/08/2015],[03/08/2015],[04/08/2015],[05/08/2015],[06/08/2015],[07/08/2015],[08/08/2015]) )
p where 1=1
```

As bluefeet said, in the PIVOT clause you need an aggregate function, but you can use your UDF in the subquery.